# MJML converts links in email clients to mjt.lu

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-mix, email-client, mjml

Laravel-mix-mjml plugin converts href links. All links work fine except one link which is a form with post request. It doesn't pass the parameters. In the browser the links are not converted. How can I fix this? Thanks

```
<mj-text>
   <form action="https://www.carsale.com/login" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" name="customerId" value="{{ $inquiry->customer->customer_id ?? '' }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="authToken" value="{{ $inquiry->customer->auth_token ?? '' }}">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Lets go</button>
   </form>
   <a href="https://www.carsale.com/login">Lets go</a>
</mj-text>
```